# Convert yearly data into time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I have an excel file in which I have yearly literacy rates data since 1961 to 2011.

```
  A tibble: 51 x 2

    YEARS  `Literacy rate(%)`
   <dbl>              <dbl>
 1  1961               18.1
 2  1962               18.3
 3  1963               18.5
 4  1964               18.7
 5  1965               18.9
 6  1966               19.1
 7  1967               19.2
 8  1968               19.4
 9  1969               19.6
 10  1970               19.8
   # ... with 41 more rows
```

I want to convert above yearly data into time series format. (start year is 1961 and end year is 2011)

I have tried other methods but it doesnt change yearly data into time series.

Please help.....

Comment: For a tibble named `mydata`, `as.ts(mydata)` should do it ?

Comment: `ts(dat$'Literacy rate(%)', start=1961)`